# How can we load pdf.dll plugin of google chrome in chromium embedded to view pdf files?

Tags: chromium

To do this I code:

```
cef_string_t sExtraPath;
memset(&sExtraPath, 0, sizeof(cef_string_t));

settings.extra_plugin_paths = cef_string_list_alloc();
CefString(&sExtraPath).FromString("pdf.dll");
cef_string_list_append(settings.extra_plugin_paths, &sExtraPath);

CefInitialize(settings, app);
```

But when opening pdf file a message like "missing plugin" displayed.

Answer (score 3):

The PDF plugin uses PPAPI which is not currently supported by CEF.
see http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-dev/browse_thread/thread/6a7c23d425a0026d